# @AppStorage fails to sync when used in multiple ObservableObject

Tags: swiftui, observation

I've been using `@AppStorage` for a long time, but it came to my attention that there seems to be an issue with how @AppStorage properties work with `ObservableObject`, or rather with multiple `ObservableObject`.

Basically, when using a shared `@AppStorage` property in two or more `ObservableObject`s, if the property is updated in one of them, the other doesn't receive the information and is effectively desynced with the actual value. Updating the desynced property triggers an update on the `View`s, but doesn't sync the value with the other `ObservableObject`s.

I recorded a video of this behavior:
https://youtube.com/shorts/kbFM2W0IvRo

Here's my sample project:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            TabAView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label {
                        Text("From View")
                    } icon: {
                        Image(systemName: "square")
                    }
                }

            TabAView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label {
                        Text("From View 2")
                    } icon: {
                        Image(systemName: "circle")
                    }
                }

            TabBView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label {
                        Text("From ObservableObj")
                    } icon: {
                        Image(systemName: "triangle")
                    }
                }

            TabBView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label {
                        Text("From ObservableObj 2")
                    } icon: {
                        Image(systemName: "fireworks")
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}

struct TabAView: View {

    @AppStorage("test") private var increment = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(increment)")

            Button {
                increment += 1
            } label: {
                Text("Increment from View")
            }
        }
    }
}

final class TabBModel: ObservableObject {
    @AppStorage("test") var increment = 0
}

struct TabBView: View {

    @StateObject private var model = TabBModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(model.increment)")

            Button {
                model.increment += 1
            } label: {
                Text("Increment from ObservableObject")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I filed a feedback to Apple over this issue: `FB13250915`.

This issue seems to have started from the moment I started building my projects with Xcode 15. I've tried building on 15.1 Beta 1, and also 14.3.1 with the same results.

I have two questions:

1. **Am I doing anything wrong?** I'm at the point of wondering if it's somehow a bad practice to use `@AppStorage` properties in more than one `ObservableObject`. Or have I missed a glaring issue in the code shown above?
2. **Is anyone affected by this issue as well?** What are you doing as of consequence? I'm considering not using `@AppStorage` anymore, but I'm not sure what the best alternative would be.

Comment: I don't think you are supposed to use `@AppStorage` in `ObservableObject`s at all. Why are you putting it in `ObservableObject`?

Comment: I believe this was initially an issue, but Apple changed the implementation so that `@AppStorage` behaves like an `@Published` property. See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios-ipados-release-notes/ios-ipados-14_5-release-notes

> AppStorage property wrappers now work as expected when contained inside an ObservableObject, causing the system to emit the objectWillChange publisher. (65562845)

Comment: I’ve noticed the same thing in Xcode 14 too

Answer (score 0):

So, I don't have a direct answer to the problem I described, but here's the workaround I found:

## Storage Controller

This ObservableObject is my replacement to @AppStorage. It's not as simple, but it works. You add it as a @StateObject to your app and you can pass it down via `EnvironmentObject`.

```swift
@StateObject private var storageController = StorageController.shared
```

You can also use it as a Singleton, and this is the way to use it in other `ObservableObject`s.

Here it is:

```swift
final class StorageController: ObservableObject {

    // MARK: - Properties

    private var tasks = [String: Task<Void,Error>]()

    @Published var codableItem: ChargingSession? = decodeFromUserDefaults(type: SomeCodable.self, key: "codableItem") {
        didSet {
            saveDataToUserDefaults(codableItem, key: "codableItem")
        }
    }

    @Published var booleanItem: Bool = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "booleanItem") {
        didSet {
            saveToUserDefaults(booleanItem, key: "booleanItem")
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Singleton

    static let shared = StorageController()
    private init() { }

    // MARK: - Helpers

    /// Save a Codable type to UserDefaults.
    ///
    /// The saving will be performed in a background queue.
    private func saveDataToUserDefaults<Value: Codable>(_ value: Value, key: String) {
        tasks[key]?.cancel()
        tasks[key] = Task(priority: .background) {
            try Task.checkCancellation()
            let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(value)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: key)
        }
    }

    private func saveToUserDefaults(_ value: Any?, key: String) {
        tasks[key]?.cancel()
        tasks[key] = Task(priority: .background) {
            try Task.checkCancellation()
            UserDefaults.standard.set(value, forKey: key)
        }
    }

}

/// Decode a Codable conforming type from UserDefaults.
func decodeFromUserDefaults<DecodedType: Codable>(type: DecodedType.Type, key: String) -> DecodedType? {
    guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: UserDefaultsKey.chargingSession()),
          let decoded = try? JSONDecoder.extended8601Decoder.decode(type, from: data) else {
        return nil
    }
    return decoded
}
```

## How to use it

In your `View`s, you can still rely on @AppStorage, no need to bother with the following.

But in your `ObservableObject`s, you can do this:

#### Step 1: Declare a property mirroring your storage value

```swift
@Published private var booleanItem: Bool = StorageController.shared.booleanItem {
    willSet {
        StorageController.shared.booleanItem = newValue
    }
}
```

Here, we do three things:

1. We set the initial value of the property with the latest value of our StorageController
2. We use willSet to update the StorageController.
3. We mark it as @Published whether this is private or not. This will come in handy in step 2.

#### Step 2: Link the property with Combine in `init`

```swift
StorageController.shared.$booleanItem
    .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
    .filter { [weak self] newValue in
        newValue != self?.booleanItem
    }
    .assign(to: &$notificationsEnabled)
```

This code ensures our property always has the latest value. The `filter` part is crucial because it prevents an infinite loop that the `willSet` above would trigger.

## Discussion and limits

- This is obviously much more work than @AppStorage was.
- However, Codable support is way easier, we don't have to parse anything to RawRepresentable
- It works well for iOS 16 (and below, I suppose?)
- I don't think this is thread-safe. I wouldn't recommend you using it as it is if you believe that could be an issue.
- Storage reads could be heavy and could slow the launch of the app since the controller basically reads everything as soon as it is instantiated.
- However, storage writes should be efficient thanks to background Tasks and Task cancellation.